# Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (40,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to classify 40 types of car logos. I used softmax and sparse_categorical_crossentropy but error still occurs. What's wrong with this code?

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_8 to have
> shape (1,) but got array with shape (40,)

My code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras

classifier=Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(32,3,3,input_shape=(50,50,3),activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=128,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=40,activation='softmax'))

loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/train_set',
        target_size=(50, 50),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(50, 50),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
classifier.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Comment: add your `dataset/train_set`  directory structure.

Comment: You are using the incorrect loss, sparse categorical crossentropy vs categorical crossentropy

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` however in your code part it is not mentioned how you have encoded the labels. If the levels are already one hot encoded then use `categorical_crossentropy` loss as sparse_categorical_crossentropy loss needs integer labels and does the one-hot encoding internally.

However it depends on the how your training dataset is which I do not see in the question here